# Move to SharePoint Online - Documents Migration related query

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, document-library, migration

We are planning to move to SP online and have a small site with a big document library having versioning enabled.

We don't need to invest in a paid tool for such small site and are thinking to use SharePoint free migration tool from the Microsoft. Does the SP Migration Tool support files migration with version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about [SharePoint Migration Tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002973) **(SPMT)**, so the answer is **YES**.

The **Version** is a supported item in SharePoint Migration Tool, and it will be preserved based on your setting.

- **Migrate file version history:** If set to Off, only the most recent version of the file will be migrated. If set to On, you can choose whether to keep all versions or limit it to a specific number.
- **Keep all versions** If set to On, all versions of a file will be migrated.
- **Number of versions to migrate** Enter a number to limit the number of file versions migrated.

[image]

> Read more, about supported items and how to use SPMT at **[SharePoint Migration Tool](https://debug.to/34/sharepoint-migration-tool)**

Answer (score 1):

Keeping versions/Version History is fully [supported](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/what-is-supported-spmt#features) while using SPMT.

One more thing you should know, if you choose to migrate all versions with the contents, make sure you have all documents/items approved/published when you have versioning enabled, since the **draft** items (which are in status of “*Pending*”) will be migrated as well.